# How to continuously write bytes to a single file in a zip archive with python

Tags: python, python-2.7, zip

I am trying to zip a couple of files to a zip archive using python. I have the following code that zips the files

```
with gcs.open(zip_file_name, 'w', content_type=b'application/zip') as f:

    with zipfile.ZipFile(f, 'w') as z:

        for file in files:

            if file.show:

                file_name = "/%s/%s" % (gcs_store.get_bucket_name(), file.gcs_name)

                gcs_reader = gcs.open(file_name, 'r',read_buffer_size=1048576)

                file_buffer = gcs_reader.read(1048576)

                while True:
                    z.writestr('%s-%s' %(file.created_on, file.name), file_buffer)
                    file_buffer = gcs_reader.read(1048576)
                    if not file_buffer:
                        break


                gcs_reader.close()

f.close() #closing zip file
```

But If I want to zip a file larger than 1MB, I would get >1 different files in the zip archive which are all at most 1MB large. That is the file is being split and the file contents are written as separate files in the zip archive.

How can I continuously write bytes to 1 file in a zip archive?

Comment: What happens if you remove the file buffer for both the read and write?

Comment: How do I read and write a file > 1 GB for instance without a buffer?